# Reading element from HTML - <td>

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-3.x, html-table

I have the following HTML:

```
<tr style='background:#DDDDDD;'>
    <td><b>ASD</b></td>
    <td colspan='3'>1231</td>
</tr>
```

This element isn't repeating on the page, so it's unique. I want to get the cell's contents (1231) into some variable. I tried using HTML.parser but it doesn't work

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look use beautifulsoup it's great,

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html) ## feed your html page to beautifulsoup

pleaseFind = soup.find(text="ASD")

whatINeed = pleaseFind.findNext('td')

print whatINeed.text
```

Comment: Soup made it :-) thanks

Comment: no problem, you can use that to find anchors, paragraphs, headers or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use urllib2 (you don't have to install anything new (at least for Windows version of Python)): http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

Example:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('your URL')
html = response.read()
#html is a string containing everything on your page

#this line (it could be a bit cleaner) finds substring "<td colspan='3'>" and
#searches between it's position and the next "</td>"
pos=html.find("<td colspan='3'>")
print html[pos+len("<td colspan='3'>")+1:html.find("</td>", pos))]
```